# What is java/scala kafka streams equivalent for KSQL join WHERE clause?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Let's say I have 2 kafka streams (kafka-streams-scala library, version 2.2.0):

```
val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
val stream1: KStream[String, GenericRecord] = builder.stream[String, GenericRecord]("topic1")
val stream2: KStream[String, GenericRecord] = builder.stream[String, GenericRecord]("topic2")
```

and their join:

```
val stream3: KStream[String, MyClass] = flights.join(schedules)((r1, r2) =>  MyClass(r1.get("f1"), r2.get("f2")), JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
```

What is the equivalent of WHERE clause available in [KSQL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/join-streams-and-tables.html#join-clause)? (see late_orders stream) for streams API? 
Is it a good idea to just use stream3.filter? Will this approach have the same efficiency as stream created by KSQL?

Comment: [`.filter`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-transformations-stateless) is the same as a `WHERE`, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the equivalent of WHERE clause available in KSQL? (see late_orders stream) for streams API?

It is:

- `KStream#filter()`, which returns a filtered `KStream`
- `KTable#filter()`, which returns a filtered `KTable`

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#stateless-transformations

> Is it a good idea to just use stream3.filter?

Yes.

> Will this approach have the same efficiency as stream created by KSQL?

Yes.